# Flutter firestore force close (error) in build apk release

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I got error at firestore stuff when build apk release, the app force close when access that firestore code. But its fine when direct running (debug) in AS/VS code. Any one can explain this?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Firestore (19.0.0).
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.j.a(:379)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.g.run(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "b.b.g.w$d b.b.g.w$d.b(int)"
    at b.b.g.r.a(:1319)
    at b.b.e.a.da.C(:5440)
    at b.b.e.a.da.a(:5509)
    at b.b.e.a.da.a(:13)
    at b.b.e.a.da$a.a(:6589)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.f.y.b(:730)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.c.h.a(:215)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.c.va.c(:103)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.c.va.a(:142)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.c.t.a(:530)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.c.q.run(Unknown Source:6)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.c.na.a(:180)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.c.t.a(:520)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.b.P.a(:178)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.b.m.a(:91)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.b.z.b(:152)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.b.v.run(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.j.a(:311)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.f.call(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.j.a(:287)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.e.run(Unknown Source:4)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.j$a.run(:205)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix this error, update `android.enableR8=false` in gradle.properties. You need to add this row cause default value **true**.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with the resource optimization (shrink code and obfuscation) when dealing with the Firestore package as seen from `java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "b.b.g.w$d b.b.g.w$d.b(int)"` which appears to be obfuscated code.

The help message from `flutter build apk -h` states that

> --[no-]shrink Whether to enable code shrinking on release mode.When enabling shrinking, you also benefit from obfuscation, which shortens the names of your app’s classes and members, and optimization, which applies more aggressive strategies to further reduce the size of your app. To learn more, see: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code (defaults to on)

You can use the `--no-shrink` tag when building the apk such as `flutter build apk --release --no-shrink` to disable shrink code and obfuscation but note that this results in a larger apk.